# Convert a video file to byte array in android

Tags: android

I can convert a string to a byte array by calling getBytes() method.How to convert a video file stored in phone storage to a byte array in android?

Comment: What is your purpose?

Comment: Unless the video is very short, you will not have enough memory to hold it in a `byte[]`.

Comment: @Kaushal28 I want to send a video file from androdi phone to a sd card attached to an arduino board